# Unable to get elements inside a list of elements using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I need to **scrape** a website that contains cards. What I want is the information inside each card. I have been able to get a list of cards like this:

```
cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='cardclass...']")
for card in cards:
    print(card.text)
    print('*'*100)
```

This prints the text of all the cards correctly. But inside loop when I do:

```
for card in cards:
    name = card.find_element_by_xpath("//h2[@class='nameclass...']")
    print(name.text)
    .  .  .  # Other elements to scrape inside a particular card
```

This keeps printing the name of just the first card. But the loop goes on up to the length of cards. The `h2` tag is inside the `cardclass` `div` tag. The structure of website is something like this:

```
<div class="cardclass">
    <h2 class="nameclass">
        <a class="..." href="..." ... >
            NAME
        </a>
    </h2>
    Other elements that also need to be scraped
    .  .  .
    .  .  .
</div>
<div.. /div>    #Second Card and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

the x-path `//h2[@class='nameclass...']` will search from top. To search from current node. you can use .(dot) like `.//h2[@class='nameclass...']`.

```
for card in cards:
    name = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//h2[@class='nameclass...']")
    print(name.text)
```

Comment: Thanks its working now but its too slow Almost more than 1 second per card and all cards are on the same page. Any idea why?

Comment: usually locating by xpath will take more time than other locators. you can use any other locator like css, classname, etc. it may be faster than x-path

Comment: Thanks but the problem was something else. I was using the full path to other elements e.g (.//div[@class=''info-primary"]/div[@class='phones phone primary'])
When I used just .//div[@class='phones phone primary'] the problem was solved

Comment: Turnsout It takes much more time when an element is not found as I am using try except for nosuchelementexception.